# Help ID wedding invite font

Tags: font-identification

[image]

wedding response card font. My Fonts couldn't ID, I also used the app. I tried just using the numbers and they appear to be Brandywine (Scriptorium). Sample was from a Brooklyn Wedding Invite.

Comment: Hmm, it's a light hand-lettering style/script style slab serif, which is pretty unusual, those search terms might help. I'd bet it was made in the last 5 years. Style reminds me of http://lauraworthingtontype.com/ but I don't think it's one of hers. Also http://www.tartworkshop.com/ have a slightly similar style

Comment: This is a tough one... Closest I can find is Lunchbox Slab which is a really good font but not a match. Judging by the kerning (e.g. L-Y) and the lack of variation I suspect this is a free font - most paid-for hand lettering fonts have neater kerning and many character variations

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure one can find this font due to the quality of the picture provided.

Probably, you can use [VTG substitution](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/voltage-ltd/vtg-juker/). I agree that it does not match the font in question, however it is hard to believe that one would prefer one upon another.

[image]